# Closing a Dojo menuItem

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to close a dojo menuItem and not sure what the correct call is.

I have this code to open the menuItem onHover:

```
        dijit._MenuBase.prototype.onItemHover = function(item) {
            if(this.isActive || this.allowSubmenuHover) {
                this.focusChild(item);
                if(this.focusedChild.popup && !this.focusedChild.disabled && !this.hover_timer){
                    this.hover_timer = setTimeout(dojo.hitch(this, '_openPopup'), this.popupDelay);
                }
            }
            if(this.focusedChild){
                this.focusChild(item);
            }
            this._hoveredChild = item;
        };
```

I have this right now when the menuItem loses focus:

```
        dijit._MenuBase.prototype.onItemUnhover = function(item) {
            alert('hi');
        };
```

I am just not sure what to replace the alert statement with to make the menuItem close.

If someone can help me I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
(you may have to add extra check to see if the mouse is not on a submenu before calling this)

```
    this._stopPopupTimer();
    item._setSelected(false);
    // Close all popups that are open and descendants of this menu
    var itemPopup = item.popup;
    if(itemPopup){
        this._stopPendingCloseTimer(itemPopup);
        itemPopup._pendingClose_timer = setTimeout(function(){
            itemPopup._pendingClose_timer = null;
            if(itemPopup.parentMenu){
                itemPopup.parentMenu.currentPopup = null;
            }
            dijit.popup.close(itemPopup); // this calls onClose
        }, this.popupDelay);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your code is kind of working.  This is what happens now....when hovering over an item and then leaving the menu and taking the mouse anywhere on the screen the menu stays and does not close.  If I take the mouse over the parent menu item on my way to a random screen location it will close correctly.  Any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks again

Comment: From what it seems, it closes when the parent's mouseout is triggered. The child's mouseout is not firing or getting canceled. Its kinda hard to say without looking at your code. Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: I haven't used jsfiddle before and I couldn't get it to work correctly so I will add my html test along with my js in a seperate answer

Comment: Was that post any helpful?  Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to set it up on my side without success so far. Its been a while since I worked with Dojo... :(

Comment: No worries.  Whenever you get a chance to look it over.  I have to close this bounty now though.  One side question do you have a certain resource or book that has been helpful with this dojo problem?  Thanks

Comment: To be honest, I used firebug to inspect their source code as I couldn't find any helpful documentation around the problem.

Comment: Have you looked at this anymore?  Still not have it working correctly

Comment: Ummm... I haven't been able to get to it. I'll try soon though.

Answer (score 1):

We have used this:

```
dijit.popup.close(menuObject);
```

with menuObject being your menu that you want to close. If you look in the dijit code it looks like that's how they close menu's.

In our project we have found that when closing a menu sometimes it doesn't clear the select highlighting so that the next time you open it the last item you selected is still highlighted. If you run in to that try using:

```
dojo.query('.dijitMenuItemSelected', menuObject.domNode).removeClass('dijitMenuItemSelected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/How-do-I-unfocus-the-menu-items-in-a-menu-td1597856.html ?

Did you try `focus`-ing another widget (or a hidden item?)

---

caveat: I have no idea if this actually helps

Comment: Thanks for the response but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my html and js source:

```
<div id="menu">
<div dojoType="dijit.MenuBar" id="menuBar">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style="float:left;margin:4px 0 0 0;outline:0 !important;color:#ccc !important;" dojoType="dijit.MenuBarItem" onclick="alert('menu')">
        Home &nbsp;
        <span style="margin:4px 12px 0 0;">|</span>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin:4px 0 0 0;;outline:0 !important;color:#ccc !important;" dojoType="dijit.PopupMenuBarItem">
            <span>System</span>
            <div dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="fileMenu" style="background:#fff !important;margin:4px 0 0;width:140px;border:1px solid #666 !important;padding:4px !important;">
                <div style="outline:0 !important;color:#333 !important;" dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" onClick="alert('hi')">Edit</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojo.parser");
dojo.require("dijit.MenuBar");
dojo.require("dijit.MenuBarItem");
dojo.require("dijit.PopupMenuBarItem");
dojo.require("dijit.Menu");
dojo.require("dijit.MenuItem");
dojo.require("dijit.PopupMenuItem");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
        dijit._MenuBase.prototype.allowSubmenuHover = true;
        dijit._MenuBase.prototype.popupDelay = 500;
        dijit._MenuBase.prototype.onItemHover = function(item) {
            if(this.isActive || this.allowSubmenuHover) {
                this.focusChild(item);
                if(this.focusedChild.popup && !this.focusedChild.disabled && !this.hover_timer){
                    this.hover_timer = setTimeout(dojo.hitch(this, '_openPopup'), this.popupDelay);
                }
            }
            if(this.focusedChild){
                this.focusChild(item);
            }
            this._hoveredChild = item;
        };
        dijit._MenuBase.prototype.onItemUnhover = function(item) {
            this._stopPopupTimer();
            item._setSelected(false);
            var itemPopup = item.popup;
            if(itemPopup){         
                this._stopPendingCloseTimer(itemPopup);
                itemPopup._pendingClose_timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    itemPopup._pendingClose_timer = null;             
                    if(itemPopup.parentMenu){                 
                        itemPopup.parentMenu.currentPopup = null;             
                    }             
                    dijit.popup.close(itemPopup); 
                }, this.popupDelay);     
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code on https://jsfiddle.net/agha_ali22/ntkhy9q3/4/ but its not working,